# Web Page Design for System Control

Tags: web, user-interface

I design small hardware systems that often require a GUI for a control interface.  The systems I work with usually have a network connection and the ability to have a simple web server.  Therefore, a web browser interface for control, operating on a LAN, is ideal since it's available on nearly all platforms.

In the past I've created the GUI page by coding HTML, JavaScript and CSS files by hand.  This is very tedious, time consuming and error prone.

I'm looking for some sort of web page design software that will assist me but so far everything I've looked at seems to be oriented towards folks designing commercial sites with fancy graphics, animations and so forth.

I'm more interested in things like buttons for user inputs and progress bars and text display areas for output, with the ability to perhaps display a graph or image.  Is there anything out there that even comes close?  The stuff I do is either for personal or open source use so I'd really prefer something that isn't too expensive.

Comment: As someone in your position, I think you may be clouding the issue by adding the word embedded. It seems to me that wall you want it drag & drop GUI design, where you will add code to to `OnClick()` events. If you agree, I would suggest that you reword this, as someone would could help you might think "embedded? Nah, I know nothing about that" & not even read the question. Btw, I recall a bunch of GUI builder questions over the years -  have you searched the site? Good luck

Comment: You could use a CSS Framework like bootstrap or UIKit to speed up the HTML/CSS Development part of it and focus on JS or insert lang here development.

Comment: Sonamor - thanks for the suggestion about bootstrap or UIKit - I was unaware of either of these.  Bootstrap looks like it might be just what I'm looking for and it has a nice tutorial on w3schools.